# Button Component not appearing properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am attempting to call my Button component inside another component however I am not getting any functionality such as onClick and its display text is also not properly appearing. However when I use just a regular button element it is working fine. I would greatly appreciate any assistance in solving this issue as this is the first time I am seeing a problem like this, thank you for your help.

[Visual of Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eVRxL.jpg)

```
 //My DeleteButton component is not giving functionality in Person component
 //onClick and hello is appearing for regular button element
 const Person = ({person}) => {
   return(
     <> 
      <div> <DeleteButton person={person}/> <button onClick={() => alert('Hello')}>hello</button> </div>
     </>
   )
 }

 //DeleteButton component
 const DeleteButton = ({person}) => {

 const handleClick = () => {
    alert(`Delete ${person.name}`)
    axios.delete('http://localhost:3001/persons').then(response => {
    console.log(response.data)
   })
 }

  return(
  <>
    <button type="button" onClick={handleClick}>Delete</button>
  </>
 )
}
```

Comment: So you mean, the alert inside the button component is not getting invoked?

Comment: Hi yes the button appears completely empty it does not show its name along with have no functionality like onClick I have added a picture for more clarification

Comment: why is there a closing div tag in Person component

Comment: My apologies I missed to include the opening div tag I had added the div for layering of the buttons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After removing the stray `</div>` and cleaning things up, it works fine for me:

```js
const Person = ({person}) =>
  <React.Fragment>
    <DeleteButton person={person} />
    <button
      onClick={() => alert('Hello')}
    >
      hello
    </button>
  </React.Fragment>
;

const DeleteButton = ({person}) => {
  const handleClick = () => {
    alert(`Delete ${person.name}`);
  };

  return (
    <button 
      type="button" 
      onClick={handleClick}
    >
      Delete
    </button>
  );
};

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector("#app"))
  .render(<Person person={{name: "foo"}} />);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```